# How to use get and set for array element in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, get, set

I have the following class:

```cs
public class test
{
    private int i;
    public test(int in)
    {
        i = in;
    }
    public int testint;
    {
        get { return i; }
        set { i = testint; }
    }
}
```

And the following code:

```cs
test[] data = new test[3];
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    data[i] = new test(0);
    data[i].testint = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine(test[0].testint);
Console.WriteLine(test[1].testint);
Console.WriteLine(test[2].testint);
```

When I run this program and type in 1, 2, 3 as the input, the output is 0, 0, 0. I don't understand why the get or set seem to be not working. If I initialize the array elements with a value other than 0, the output will be that. The data[i].testint = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); seems to not be working. How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: That setter doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3):

You setter is incorrect. It should be:

```
 set { i = value; }
```

You had:

```
 set { i = testint; }
```

Which only triggers the getter, which gets from `i`, so in the end your setter was doing `i = i` .

In a setter, the `value` keyword contains the new candidate value for the property. `value`'s type equals the property's. I say candidate value because you can validate it and choose to not apply it.

In your case, you were not applying the value.

**Update**

Also, when defining getters and setters, no semicolon should be used. Code, then, would look like this:

```
public int testint
{
    get { return i; }
    set { i = value; }
}
```

Comment: This only addresses one of the syntax errors pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @JonathanWood You are right. No need to downvote, though. Answer is fixed.

Comment: Whether there was reason to downvote or not, I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @JonathanWood It's cool though, at least the answer is more complete now. Hope it helps OP and future browsers

Answer (score 3):

I see two errors in this code:

```
public int testint;
{
    get { return i; }
    set { i = testint; }
}
```

There should be no semicolon after `testint` at the top. Also, `set` needs to assign using `value`, like this:

```
public int testint
{
    get { return i; }
    set { i = value; }
}
```

Comment: Allow me to just disagree a little. There are **not** 2 syntax errors:  there's one syntax error and one semantic error. The setter is not syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Change the set method to this:

```
public int testint
{
   get { return i; }
   set { i = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your setter to say:

```
set { i = value; }
```

value corresponds to the value you send to set the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's simple way.

```
public int TestInt {get; set;}
```